# Функция и массив

Tags: javascript

Взял данный скрипт из учебника.

Не могу понять, что делают последние 5 строк, пожалуйста объясните.

```js
function sumInput() {

  let numbers = [];

  while (true) {

    let value = prompt("Введите число", 0);

    // Прекращаем ввод?
    if (value === "" || value === null || !isFinite(value)) break;

    numbers.push(+value);
  }

  let sum = 0;                          // Что 
  for (let number of numbers) {        //  делает
    sum += number;                    //   этот
  }                                  //    фрагмент
  return sum;                       //     кода?
}

alert( sumInput() );
```

Comment: @Doofy, лучше пусть и спрашивает нас. Чем потом не знать многого.

Comment: А кто мой коммент удалил?

Comment: @kotleni ну так вы здесь не одни

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не несёт пользы другим участникам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let sum = 0;                          // сумма 
  for (let number of numbers) {        //  перебор всех значений массива numbers
    sum += number;                    //   добавить значение к сумме
  }                                  //    ...
  return sum;                       //     вернуть сумму
```

Данный код делает это:

- Принимает введенные данные
- По команде перестает их принимать
- Суммирует, и возвращает результат

Comment: По какой команде перестает их принимать?

Comment: Если отправить пустую строку.

Comment: А зачем нужна начальная сумма в лице нолика.

Comment: Что бы sum не был undefined.

Comment: Всегда нужно прописывать нолик в похожих операциях?

Comment: Это называется инициализацией, просто имейте привычку инициализировать переменные перед использованием.

Comment: sum += number;  Какое значение добавляет к сумме?

Comment: += это упрощение, по сути одно и тоже: sum = sum + number.

Comment: @Человек это как в жизни. Чему будет равно неизвестно + 10? Вы не сможете такое сложить. А чему будет равно 0 + 10? На это вы знаете ответ. Программа точно такая же. Она без понятия, что может быть под словом undefined

Answer (score 2):

Это:

```js
let sum = 0;                          
for (let number of numbers) {        
  sum += number;                    
}
```

Работает также, как и:

```js
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  sum += number;
}
```

Т.е. в данном случае это простой цикл, которой проходится по всему массиву